# Firebase Hosting - I can not confirm my domain

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

1.Connect Domain

2.Add Domain ex: example.com -> Continue

3.DNS Management My Provider

4.Verify ownership

Questions: How do I solve this problem?
Thanks

Comment: Have you added DNS text to your provider account?

Comment: Screenshoot. 1. http://prntscr.com/elfzww   2. http://prnt.sc/elg0el  3. http://prntscr.com/elg0rs

Comment: Please clarify your question, what kind of problem you are facing?

Comment: @AnujJPandey Yes, I have, but failed when the verify, I've added some screenshots, please check, thanks

Comment: Please wait for some time as DNS setting takes some time some of the vendor provide option to select the activation time like goddady and some do it automatically after some time.

Comment: @AnujJPandey I will go back, if verify success or failed, thanks

Comment: If the domain registration still doesn't propagate after more than 24 hours, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting. There is nothing we can do here, since you seem reluctant to share your domain name.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Hai.. Frank thank you for helping me, this is my domain http://samsulbari.com

Comment: When I run `$ dig -t txt +noall +answer samsulbari.com` I get 
`;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached`. So it looks like your domain hasn't shown up in any DNS that I can find yet. Test if that command works for you.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have contacted the service Domain Provider, and the response of my domain is active, but I still can not verify DNS in Firebase.

Is there any advanced settings related to my issue?

Please help, thanks.

Comment: That domain still isn't active. You need to go back to your provider and have *them* check it as it's not reachable from outside their network.